# Android Manifest Required Permission Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

On Xamarin.Forms I try to add `Call_Phone`Permission, but as soon as I click the list view in Visual Studio to tick it I get this error:`Value cannot be null`.

I noticed all the other fields in Manifest tab are empty, I don't know if that's normal, but if I try to fill them I get that error with each key stroke.

Even when I try to close the page I get that error so I have to unload the project altogether.
What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Add the key manually in the manifest file. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`. You will find your mainfest file in your project folder.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked when I filled the fields.